# AWS S3 HTTPS API request(URL) signed with temporary security credentials to access object

Tags: amazon-s3

How to generate the HTTPS API request(URL) signed with temporary security credentials  to access AWS S3 object.I am able to access object using amazon java sdk but I would like to generate the complete url with temporary security credential like pre signed url.
package com.siriusxm.repo.test;

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

import com.amazonaws.auth.BasicSessionCredentials;
import com.amazonaws.auth.profile.ProfileCredentialsProvider;
import com.amazonaws.regions.Region;
import com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client;
import com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.GetObjectRequest;
import com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.ObjectListing;
import com.amazonaws.services.securitytoken.AWSSecurityTokenServiceClient;
import com.amazonaws.services.securitytoken.model.Credentials;
import com.amazonaws.services.securitytoken.model.GetSessionTokenRequest;
import com.amazonaws.services.securitytoken.model.GetSessionTokenResult;
import com.siriusxm.repo.DownloadServiceImpl;

public class TemporaryCredential {

    private static String bucketName = "myrepo"; 
    private static String key  =  "test.pdf";

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("");

        AWSSecurityTokenServiceClient stsClient = new AWSSecurityTokenServiceClient(
                new ProfileCredentialsProvider());
    //  stsClient.setRegion(regionName);sts.us-west-2.amazonaws.com
        //
        // Start a session.
        GetSessionTokenRequest getSessionTokenRequest = new GetSessionTokenRequest();
        GetSessionTokenResult sessionTokenResult = stsClient
                .getSessionToken(getSessionTokenRequest);
        Credentials sessionCredentials = sessionTokenResult.getCredentials();
        System.out.println("Session Credentials: "
                + sessionCredentials.toString());
        // Package the session credentials as a BasicSessionCredentials
        // object for an S3 client object to use.
        BasicSessionCredentials basicSessionCredentials = new BasicSessionCredentials(
                sessionCredentials.getAccessKeyId(),
                sessionCredentials.getSecretAccessKey(),
                sessionCredentials.getSessionToken());

        AmazonS3Client s3object = new AmazonS3Client(basicSessionCredentials);
        // Test. For example, get object keys for a given bucket.
        ObjectListing objects = s3object.listObjects(bucketName);
        s3object.getObject( new GetObjectRequest(bucketName, key));
        System.out.println("No. of Objects = "
                + objects.getObjectSummaries().size());
    }
}
```

This code generate the dynamically access key,secret key and security token.Now i need to generate url with authorization header with signature so that i can access S3 object directly.Is there way?

From this code i want to generate url using x-amz-security-token

Answer (score 5):

if you want to do this in java, you have to use [AmazonS3.generatePresignedUrl](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/fr_fr/AmazonS3/latest/dev/ShareObjectPreSignedURLJavaSDK.html)

```
AmazonS3 s3client = new AmazonS3Client(new ProfileCredentialsProvider()); 

java.util.Date expiration = new java.util.Date();
long msec = expiration.getTime();
msec += 1000 * 60 * 60; // 1 hour.
expiration.setTime(msec);

GeneratePresignedUrlRequest generatePresignedUrlRequest = 
              new GeneratePresignedUrlRequest(bucketName, objectKey);
generatePresignedUrlRequest.setMethod(HttpMethod.GET); // Default.
generatePresignedUrlRequest.setExpiration(expiration);

URL s = s3client.generatePresignedUrl(generatePresignedUrlRequest);
```

if you want to do this from the console, go to you s3 bucket, click download on the object. This displays a box where you can click on "download". If you right click on this link and copy the address link, you get a pre-signed url for this object

Comment: @Tom-I want to generate url using STS using following code-
AWSSecurityTokenServiceClient stsClient = new AWSSecurityTokenServiceClient(
    new ProfileCredentialsProvider());
  
How to generate https url using temporary security credential using x-amz-security-token.Please help

Comment: STS is a web service that enables you to request temporary credentials for IAM users or federated users, but this is not a way to obtain a pre-signed url for s3. What you can do is: first use sts to obtain temporary IAM credentials (with a policy allowing you to get objects from s3), and then pre-sign urls with generatePresignedUrl as shown in my answer, using these temporary credentials. Please note that a pre-signed url is temporary valid and "uses" temporary credentials behind the scene.

Comment: if needed, here is how to create a client with temporary credentials: BasicSessionCredentials basic_session_creds = new BasicSessionCredentials(
   session_creds.getAccessKeyId(),
   session_creds.getSecretAccessKey(),
   session_creds.getSessionToken());

AmazonS3Client s3 = new AmazonS3Client(basic_session_creds);

Comment: @Tom-I have generate the temporary credential like access key,secret key and security token.Please find the attached code..Now I need to generate url using these credential with authorization header with signature

Comment: why don't you just add as I suggest in my answer? you can print the url by just doing 
System.out.println("url is" + s);, with "s" being the variable as described in my answer. Am i missunderstanding your needs?

Comment: I want to Authenticate my https request using temporary credential not generating pre signed url.As Authentiacte request using temporary credential and presigned url are two different thing.I want to generate url using temporary credential(access key,secret key,and token) share the this url to client to access S3 object.As i assume my env is less secure so I want to go for temporary credential to access the S3 object

Comment: "I want to generate url using temporary credential(access key,secret key,and token) share the this url to client to access S3 object" ==> this is the definition of a pre-signed url, see http://docs.aws.amazon.com/fr_fr/AmazonS3/latest/dev/ShareObjectPreSignedURL.html. A pre-singed url does not embed your credentials, so no need to generate it using temporary credentials.

Comment: Thanks but if i want to achieve same thing using below link
<<Example HTTPS API request signed with temporary security credentials>>
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/id_credentials_temp_use-resources.html

Comment: This is exactly the same as what I describe, except that you link to the REST api, and I link to the corresponding sdk java call. That's why I say that signed urls use temporary credentials behind the scene. If you do as described in my answer, you will get an url allowing access to the object for your client (or any person that has this url), and this url will have temporary credentials. This is 100% best practice as of today

Comment: just try it, i m sure you will understand what i mean by reading the url generated :)